# How to convert a list into a column in python?

Tags: python

I have a list that content 5000 numbers. 
and it looks like this

```
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to multiple this matrix with another matrix.
Therefore, I want to convert it to a column.

```
y' =[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
```

I try to use `zip(*y)`. But an error occurs `"zip argument #1 must support iteration"`
thank you so much for helping.

Comment: If you're doing mathematics forget about lists, use numpy. Trust me, I do a lot of that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions:

```
>>> y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> [[i] for i in y]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider switching to `numpy` for efficient vector and matrix operations.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: %paste
y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

## -- End pasted text --

In [3]: a = np.array(y)

In [4]: a
Out[4]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [5]: np.dot(a, a)
Out[5]: 91
```

With a matrix:

```
In [7]: M = np.matrix(np.arange(0, 15, 0.5).reshape((6, 5)))

In [8]: M
Out[8]:
matrix([[  0. ,   0.5,   1. ,   1.5,   2. ],
        [  2.5,   3. ,   3.5,   4. ,   4.5],
        [  5. ,   5.5,   6. ,   6.5,   7. ],
        [  7.5,   8. ,   8.5,   9. ,   9.5],
        [ 10. ,  10.5,  11. ,  11.5,  12. ],
        [ 12.5,  13. ,  13.5,  14. ,  14.5]])

In [9]: a * M
Out[9]: matrix([[ 175. ,  185.5,  196. ,  206.5,  217. ]])
```

or simply:

```
In [10]: M = np.arange(0, 15, 0.5).reshape((6, 5))

In [11]: np.dot(a, M)
Out[11]: array([ 175. ,  185.5,  196. ,  206.5,  217. ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y' = [[i] for i in y]
```

would do that

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying would work with a 2D array:

```
 >>> z = [[1,2,3,4,5,6]]
 >>> zip(*z)
 [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

Although, now you have a list of tuples, instead of a list of lists.

As I understand it, zip exists to take sets of iterables (irritables(?)) and return a list of tuples, where the nth tuple contains the nth items from each iterable.

When you took a 1D list and applied '*' to it, you unpacked the list before passing it to zip. So,

```
  y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  zip(*y)
```

Was the same as

```
  y = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
  zip(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

which, as the error stated, was asking zip to work with arguments that don't support iteration.